# Rotating 3D Boolean Mask from desired location in Python

Tags: python, numpy, rotation, image-rotation

I have a 3D Boolean array which I want to rotate around a desired point or coordinate, not just randomly. How can I achieve this in python? I know I can use scipy.ndimage.rotate, but the problem is that it rotates the array around the center, but I want to rotate around a specific point. Here is my boolean mask:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import skimage
from skimage import draw

mask = skimage.draw.ellipsoid(10,12,16)
```

If I rotate using rotation matrix, how can I specify that I wish to rotate my 3D Boolean mask around this given location or point? For example, the mask in the code above is an ellipsoid. How can one rotate the ellipsoid around one of the ends ?